# OpenGl ES 2.0 Load texture junkwise

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I am currently playing around with the NDK on Android and OpenGL ES 2.0. I am wondering whether and if how it is possible to load an OpenGl texture junkwise so I can avoid to have the entire uncompressed texture in the app heap just before giving it to OpenGl. So, what I'd like to do (simplfied) ist read 512Kb from the storage into RAM, then transfer these 512kb to OpenGl, then load the next 512kb into RAM and so on - therefore the memory footprint for texture loading should always be around 512Kb. What I see in all the examples on OpenGL however is that people tend to load the ENTIRE uncomressed image data into RAM (64MB for a 4096x4096x32bit texture!. And then copy the entire data to OpenGl at once. Having a memory footprint peak of 64MB just for loading a texture!! :-O I am wondering even more as I think to know, that an app written in java running within the Dalvik VM usually only has 16Mb of available heap memory - so how do they manage to even load a texture into OpenGL? I am missing something elementary here?

Many thanks and best regards
Samuel

Comment: Apps haven't had a 16MB managed heap limit since 2009.  Still, 64MB is a rather large amount of data for a single texture on a mobile device, and it would be better to use a compressed texture format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a texture can be loaded in junks.

The way to do this is to first call `glTexImage2D()` with the full size, and a null pointer for the last argument where you would otherwise pass a pointer to the data. This specifies the size and format for the texture, but does not fill it with data.

After that, `glTexSubImage2D()` can be used to fill the texture with blocks of data.

For example, to fill a 4096x4096 RGBA texture with 1024x1024 size blocks:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 4096, 4096, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data00);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1024, 0, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data01);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 2048, 0, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data02);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3072, 0, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data03);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 1024, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data10);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data11);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 2048, 1024, 1024, 1024,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data12);
...
```

If you really do need textures this big, you may want to consider using compressed textures. Unfortunately support for specific compressed texture formats is device dependent in ES 2.0. But considering how much it can reduce memory usage, and possibly improve performance/power, it might still be worth looking into. Check out `glCompressedTexImage2D()` for a starting point.

Of course you also want to make sure that your assets are not higher resolution than needed.